# Pascal triangle with more numbers to add

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, binomial-coefficients

I've found a way to make variants of Pascal's Triangle, by changing the number of values from the previous row to add up.

In this triangle I add three numbers.

```
             1
           1 1 1 
         1 2 3 2 1 
       1 3 6 7 6 3 1 
   1 4 10 16 19 16 10 4 1 
1 5 15 30 45 51 45 30 15 5 1
```

In this one I add six.

```
                                1 
                           1 1 1 1 1 1 
                      1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 
            1 3 6 10 15 21 25 27 27 25 21 15 10 6 3 1 
1 4 10 20 35 56 80 104 125 140 146 140 125 104 80 56 35 20 10 4 1
```

Has this been studied before?  Where can I find more information about it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your English, but what is the pattern behind these numbers?

Comment: This is not exactly what you are looking at, but you may be interested in [Pascal's pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_pyramid), or more generally [Pascal's simplices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_simplex).

Comment: Sum of elements in row equals root**row_num, if you asked about algorithm I write it here within a few hours.

Comment: Seems like you are looking at the coefficients of $(1+X+X^2+\cdots+X^{r-1})^n$; for various $r$ (and all $n$); that certainly has been looked at by people.

Comment: For the second triangle see [A063260 at OEIS](https://oeis.org/A063260).

Comment: @TobyMak i make a visualization https://imgur.com/xO8ugYn, and public source here https://pastebin.com/S8YBYqrS if need, i can write on python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good news: this is a studied phenomenon!  In fact, the fourth row in the 6-item grouping is one I know by heart from using it so often.

In general, we have this relationship:

$$x_m(r,c) = \begin{cases}
1&\text{if }r=c=0\\
0&\text{if }r>c\times(m-1)\text{ or }c < 0\\
\sum_{k=c-m+1}^cx_m(r-1,k)&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

This can be interpreted as the number of ways the sum of a set of $r$ $m$-sided dice that start at $0$ can add up to $c$.

There is also a generating function formula by rows that's really nice:
$$\left(\frac{x^m-1}{x-1}\right)^r$$

The arrays for several of these exist in OEIS, indexed here by $m$: [2](http://oeis.org/A007318), [3](http://oeis.org/A027907), [4](http://oeis.org/A008287), [5](http://oeis.org/A035343), [6](http://oeis.org/A063260), [7](http://oeis.org/A063265), [8](http://oeis.org/A171890), [9](http://oeis.org/A213652), [10](http://oeis.org/A213651)

Answer (score 1):

From a computing point of view, you are applying a 1D convolution with a kernel of ones over an array of numbers padded with zeros in order to get each successive line. If I was programming this, I would start with a list containing 1, then pad it with n-1 zeros on either side and then perform a convolution operation containing kernel with n 1s over the array. This will give an array giving the next line. Then repeat the process again for the next line. I would have no idea about getting a formula for it though!